# How to consume Magnolia REST API to render UI in native iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, content-management-system, mobile-application, magnolia

We need to load static UI pages in iOS native App using Magnolia REST API JSON.
Is there any SDK to work with that JSON? I searched every possible thing but got nothing.
Any leads or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For basic usage there is no SDK - you can use standard Swift teqniques to hit a REST endpoint with the Magnolia endpoints.

Some examples
https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/Getting-started-with-Magnolia/Getting-started-with-REST.html

Endpoint Documentation
https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/Developing/API/REST-API/Delivery-endpoint-API/Delivery-endpoint-API-v2.html

For more advanced usage with React, Angular or Vue, Magnolia does have SDKs. That is described here:
https://hd.magnolia-cms.com/docs/getting-started/hello-spa